# Found leaks when adding IBOutlets specially UIimageview in interface builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, uiimageview

When i am adding IBOutlet UIImage *name and connect it with interface builder, then it gives me Leaks. How can i remove this leaks.?

```
IBOutlet UIImageView * growbar;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   UIImageView * growbar;

@synthesize growbar;
```

After that, I will connect it to interface builder by drpping UIImageview on view and connect..

[image]

This is when i was adding iboutlet.

Comment: Do you release this property in the corresponding `dealloc` method?

Comment: I have release this in **dealloc** method

Comment: Ok. Another thing: does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484022/memory-leak-for-uiimageview/3484895#3484895) help?

Comment: No , I am already running on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am not retain IBoutlet just release in deaaloc and not recieve any warning

Answer (score 0):

Are you clearing your IBOutlets in your viewDidUnload?

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [self setGrowbar:nil];
}
```

If your view is unloaded for any reason (probably low memory) then you will leak your IBOutlet objects unless you release them specifically in viewDidUnload.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view controller owning these outlets actually released?

You can check by either placing log/breakpoint in dealloc, or seeing the VC as a leak himself in Instruments.